# Wordpress site with php script does not work after publishing

Tags: php, html, wordpress, calendar

I have a site on a Wordpress and I wanted to have fully modifiable (styls etc.) google calendar.

I used pp script (below)

```
<?php
$your_google_calendar="https://calendar.google.com/calendar/embed?src=c2hkshh3lilu6ig3p1899gonqc%40group.calendar.google.com&ctz=Europe%2FWarsaw";

$url= parse_url($your_google_calendar);
$google_domain = $url['scheme'].'://'.$url['host'];

// Load and parse Google's raw calendar
$dom = new DOMDocument;
$dom->loadHTMLfile($your_google_calendar);

// Create a link to a new CSS file called schedule.min.css
$element = $dom->createElement('link');
$element->setAttribute('type', 'text/css');
$element->setAttribute('rel', 'stylesheet');
$element->setAttribute('href', 'schedule.min.css');

// Change Google's JS file to use absolute URLs
$scripts = $dom->getElementsByTagName('script');

foreach ($scripts as $script) {
  $js_src = $script->getAttribute('src');
  
  if ($js_src) {
    $parsed_js = parse_url($js_src, PHP_URL_HOST);
    if (!$parsed_js) {
      $script->setAttribute('src', $google_domain . $js_src);      
    }
  }
}

 // Append this link at the end of the element
$head = $dom->getElementsByTagName('head')->item(0);
$head->appendChild($element);

// Remove old stylesheet
$oldcss = $dom->documentElement;
$link = $oldcss->getElementsByTagName('link')->item(0);
$head->removeChild($link);

// Export the HTML
echo $dom->saveHTML();
?>
```

I've put (using Elementor) a html code on my website:

```
<iframe style="border-width: 0;" src="./wp-content/themes/neve/calendar.php" width="560" height="400" frameborder="0" scrolling="no"></iframe>
```

And everything worked until this site was set as a DRAFT. When I hit Publised button, I've got error, ok, maybe not error but instead of loading a google calendar as a part of my site I've got defualt 'page not found' screen from my wordpress site.

Is there anyone who knows what happend after publishing, that this site is not working?
If I go back to draft, site is working again.

My php script and css file are in: ./wp-content/themes/neve/ folder.

EDIT EDIT EDIT

.css example from my project to show you what I mean by 'fully modifiable'.

```
.view-container-border {
    background: transparent;
}

.view-cap {
    background: transparent;
}

.mv-event-container { 
    border-top: 1px solid black; 
}

.mv-daynames-table { 
    color: black; 
    background: transparent; 
    text-transform: uppercase;
}

.st-dtitle {
    background: #EAEAEA;
    text-align: center;
}

.st-bg-today, .st-dtitle-today {
    background: #EAEAEA;
    border: none;
    text-align: center;
}
```

And thanks to that my calendar looks like:
ps. "zajęty (a)" means that this is a public calendar which have 'show only busy' option set on.
[image]

Comment: What is fully modifiable? You want your google calendar embedded in your page, with whatever parameters you assign (CSS, Google, etc.)?

Comment: Yes, when I implemented above solution on a page which was set as a Draft, I could change all the elements with help of css file.
I've added a .css code of my example in a main post.

Comment: Would you include the order in which you're enqueuing  the CSS in your `functions.php`? Perhaps that ordering or alternatively caching is causing your problem...

Comment: I did not change functions.php at all. 
I've just added new file calendar.php and put it into the code of my page.

Answer (score 0):

Embedding your Google calendar may be done within your theme by including the Google provided `<iframe>` for embedding the calendar. This code they provide on the calender's settings page should be pasted into one of your templates. Instead of trying to build out the `<iframe>` tag with PHP put it within one of your PHP templates within your theme. Depending on your theme this may be any number of templates but whichever one it is, just include the `<iframe>` tag that should resemble this one:

`<iframe src="https://calendar.google.com/calendar/embed?src=c2hkshh3lilu6ig3p1899gonqc%40group.calendar.google.com&ctz=Europe%2FWarsaw" style="border: 0" width="800" height="600" frameborder="0" scrolling="no"></iframe>`

For example, if you wanted to place your calendar on a hypothetical 'contact' page then within the template `content.php` you place your `<iframe>` tag provided by Google which you have already located in [the Google calendar settings](https://calendar.google.com/calendar/u/0/r/settings/).

```
<?php 
.......
?>
<h1>My Google Calendar</h1>
<iframe src="https://calendar.google.com/calendar/embed?src=c2hkshh3lilu6ig3p1899gonqc%40group.calendar.google.com&ctz=Europe%2FWarsaw" style="border: 0" width="800" height="600" frameborder="0" scrolling="no"></iframe>
```

Comment: But putting calendar in that way does not allow me to attac a css file and change any of the classes and styles. And te main problem is I don't want to have ugly looking google calendar on my site.

Comment: https://developers.google.com/calendar/ ..... https://developers.google.com/calendar/quickstart/php